# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(f^{-1}[n,\infty])=\mu(f^{-1}\{\infty\})$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a $\mathscr{E}$-measurable function. Is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(f^{-1}[n,\infty])=\mu(f^{-1}\{\infty\})$

If so how do you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  false in general. (It is true for finite measures). If $\mu$ Is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=x$ for all $x$ then LHS is $\infty$ and RHS is $0$.

Comment: What if we are given also that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(f^{-1}[n,\infty])=0$ ?

Comment: @greenonion Then  the conclusion holds. If we just know that $\mu(f^{-1}[n ,\infty]) <\infty$ for some $n$  then the conclusion holds.

Answer (score 2):

This is continuity of the measure : If $\mu(E_1)<\infty $ and $E_1\supset E_2\supset E_3...$, then $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}E_i\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mu(E_n).$$

---

And as said *Kavi Rama Murthy*, if there is no $i\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\mu(E_i)<\infty $, then the statement is not true.